# glDrawElements doesn't draw all geometry

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, vuforia

I'm having trouble trying to draw a custom model at Vuforia iOS example but it's just OpengGLES 2.0 code. It has a lot of vertices (+100 K), but for tests I'm just assigning a custom color at my fragment shader and this works ok, tested with another models. For now i'm not using VBO until this works.

TESFPositions it's a floats array: x,y,z,x,y,z...
TESFIndices it's a GLuint array.

```
glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&modelViewProjection.data[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, TESFPositions);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
//glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, TESFVertices); <-- Works fine
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(TESFIndices) / sizeof(GLuint), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLvoid*)TESFIndices); <-- Some geometry is missing
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem....?

Comment: It doesn't draw all geometry, as topic says. It's an historic building and some exterior faces are missing while using glDrawElements, but they appear ok using the same code but glDrawArrays (commented line)

Answer (score 0):

It is a common issue to have an overflow due to a small capacity on the index buffer count. The index is most likely a 16 bit unsigned integer which results in largest index can be just over 65k (65545 I believe).

To solve this issue try to change the format to a larger value but understand that not all devices support larger then 16 bit indices. In case it is not supported you need to break your model into a few smaller ones. You can do that either at design time or at load time.

Comment: According to what I have [read](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Type), unsigned integer are 32 bit value, unsigned short are 16. That's why I'm using gluint for indices.

Comment: I see but still there is a reason to suspect this is exactly what the issue is. This overflow could also happen in the importer which can be checked by printing the largest index value before the draw call or can happen internally (your GLuint is ignored)...